# Alternative to Jenkins Extended Choice Parameter plugin?

Tags: jenkins, automation, build-server

The Jenkins "Extended Choice Parameter" plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) has been marked "vulnerable" on the Jenkins website for some time.

Does Jenkins have a similar plugin for dynamically populating menus, but that's not vulnerable?

If not, is there another automation server or building service with a similar feature that you can recommend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) for dynamically-generated parameters.

Comment: This plugin satisfies my need for providing dynamic params on Jenkins. Thanks